# NextJS: I am getting undefined from api json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting undefined in console log instead of data

**My Index.js (pages file)**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import axios from "axios";
import Test from "../components/Test";

import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Test />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**My Test.js (components file) from which i get error**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Test({ data }) {
    console.log(data);
    return <div>Check console log log</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`
    );
    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
}

export default Test;
```

**Console Output**

```
undefined
```

Please help me i dont know why axios, fetch doesnt work components but working in *pages/index.js*

Comment: Probably your data is an Array, so try a for and print the data

Comment: data.userId returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserId' of undefined

Comment: but are you using a For?

Answer (score 2):

According to Next.js docs `getStaticProps` method works on [Page Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)  but not in child components. You called in `Test` which is child component.

What You can do fetch data in your page component than pass the data via props & then you can access the data from child component If you are trying to use `getStaticProps`.

Example:

**Index.js**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import axios from "axios";
import Test from "../components/Test";

import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

function Home({ data }) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Test data={data} />
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
   const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`
   );
   return {
      props: {
        data,
     },
  };
}

export default Home;
```

**Test Component:**

```
import React from "react";

function Test({ data }) {
    console.log(data);
    return <div>Check console log log</div>;
}
export default Test;
```

**Without getStaticProps  & data directly in child component:**

**Index.js:(Page)**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import Test from "../components/Test";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Test />
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

**Test.js(Component):**

```
import React from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";


const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

function Test() {
    const { data } = useSWR('yourURL', fetcher);

    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
    return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! data passed from pages/index.js to components/Test.js

I found that "getStaticProps" doent supported in components only in pages dont know why it doesnt supported